# How to set whole app style with condition in angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to have a button to set the whole app to dark mode.

1. a toggle switch for "dark mode"
2. this toggle switch will toggle a boolean value "dark-ui" true/false
3. when the app component reads dark-ui as true, the class "dark" should be set on one of the parent-level elements, such as app-main. When dark-ui is false, this class should be removed.

So I had this toggle in the footer component. I try to use [ngClass], but it is not what I wanted.

toggle in html file

```
<button *ngIf="isDarkMode==false" md-button (click)="turnOnDarkMode()">Dark Mode Off</button>

<button *ngIf="isDarkMode!=false" md-button (click)="turnOffDarkMode()">Dark Mode On</button>
```

ts file

```
turnOnDarkMode() {

}

turnOffDarkMode() {

}
```

What I should do in the two functions, or is there any other approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Just have a look at this https://dev.to/adamaso/angular-6-dynamic-themes-without-a-library-2e9c and also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-kUmbmBVLo

Answer (score 1):

the best way to go about it is using `[class.setDarkMode]="darkMode"` or `[ngClass]="darkMode"` and then in your ts file you can

```
turnOnDarkMode() {
  this.darkMode=true;
}

turnOffDarkMode() {
  this.darkMode=true;
}
```

It's preferred to use `ngClass` attribute as it has much richer functionality visit this [link](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngclass-ngstyle/) to check on the use cases.

And for the css to run by to turn on the dark mode

```
root: {
  --text-color: DarkBlue;
  --back-color: Azure;
}
body { color: var(--text-color); background: var(--back-color)}
@media (prefers-dark-interface) {
  root: {
   --text-color: Azure;
   --back-color: DarkBlue;
  } 
}
```

reference this [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-dark-mode-working-with-css-740ad31e22e) for further details on the css